# Create Stripe plan on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, stripe-payments

I'm using Laravel 5.1, and I'm thinking of a way to create a plan without going to my Stripe account.

I used:

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php 2.*
```

Then I did this in my controller:

```
use \Stripe\Plan;

Plan::create(array(
          "amount" => 2000,
          "interval" => "monthly",
          "name" => "Amazing Gold Plan",
          "currency" => "usd",
          "id" => "gold")
);
```

And got the following error:

> Class 'Stripe\Plan' not found

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance if you know what to do.

Comment: I supouse the stripe package requires register a service provider and alias for the facade. Did you check that?

Comment: i think i did not sir. im quite new to laravel. do you have any idea how can i do that?

Comment: Why are you using Stripe v2.* when there's v4.5.0 available?

Comment: its not a big deal to me what version to use as long as its working sir. my problem is that I include a package using the composer and cant access it in my controller

Comment: @mendz I'm saying it's possible using such an outdated version is part of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it seems like your Strip class is not being loaded, I review the documentation and the library is a PHP library not a Laravel package
You could load it on the Autoload section on the composer.json but if you are already using Laravel I really recommend you to use Laravel Cashier and simply follow the steps of the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing

It should be something like this... I recommend you to check the composer documentation

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Stripe\\": "vendor/your/stripe/path",
    },
}
```

Comment: im using 5.1 and i would also want to stick on the documentation but it doesn't include adding plan and even retrieving available plan. but stripe documentation has a code for it. im new to laravel and have to idea on how to add a package that is not provided by laravel. and i see this require stripe/stripe-php 2.* code and try it. it was loaded successfully but i cant access it in my controller.

Comment: I already update the answer, but I recommend you to check how the autoload works